# xCode Thread 1:EXC_Arithmetic(code=EXC_1386_DIV,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, arc4random

Getting the error above causing my iOS app to crash. Never seen this before and was wondering if anyone could help me? I'm new to coding and taking on my first app without following lessons/tutorials.

```
-(void)updateGamePlay {

    int numberOfImages = (int)[self.mainImages count];
    int randomIndex = arc4random() % numberOfImages;
    MainImage *imageView = [self.mainImages objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

    self.mainImageView.image = imageView.mainTextImage;
}
```

It appears on the second line with the
`int randomIndex = arc4random() % numberOfImages;`

What i have is an array called mainImages.
That array holds objects which have a property of UIImage called mainTextImage.
Inside this method, I am trying to set mainTextImage equal to mainImageView.image so that when this method is called, one of those images are randomly selected to be displayed in the mainImageView.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `numberOfImages` at the point the exception occurs? Are you sure `mainImages` isn't empty? To me, it seems like you might be dividing by zero.

Comment: The numberOfImages is supposed to be equal to the number of objects the array 'mainImages'. That way, one random object inside that array can display the defined image it is associated with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo! - Read the comments

```
- (NSArray *)mainImages {

MainImage *purpleText = [[MainImage alloc] init];
purpleText.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purpleText.png"];

MainImage *whiteText = [[MainImage alloc] init];
whiteText.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteText.png"];

MainImage *blackText = [[MainImage alloc] init];
blackText.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackText.png"];

NSArray *mainImages = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // Here is where you create the array
return mainImages; // Here is where you return the newly created empty array
```

}

To make this work I will need to know what the Main Image class is / does or do you just want to fill the array with images and return it?

Also

This

```
MainImage *purpleText = [[MainImage alloc] init];
purpleText.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purpleText.png"];
```

is a mega confusing naming convention. The use of the words image and text are clashing with each other. I'd rename this stuff to mean what it's named i.e.

```
MainImage *purpleTextImage = [[MainImage alloc] init];
purpleTextImage.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purpleTextImage.png"];
```

The people who have to work on your code down the line will thank you for the clarity. :)

Comment: All i'm trying to do is fill the array with images then bring it into my view controller so that the can randomly be selected to display when that method is called upon.

And i see what you're saying about the names haha. I had trouble coming up with some. I'll keep that in mind to do better in the future and fix those now!

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int numberOfImages = (int)[self.mainImages count];
```

Should be

```
int numberOfImages = [self.mainImages count];
```

I'm presuming self.mainImages is an array object and has been initialised and populated. Put a breakpoint on your crashing line and check. The error looks like a divide by zero error to me.

EDIT:

I knocked this up to show you have an issue elsewhere. Definitely double check the array has values.

```
NSMutableArray *testQuicklyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
{
    [testQuicklyArray addObject:myImage];
}

self.mainImages = [testQuicklyArray copy];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int numberOfImages = [self.mainImages count];
    int randomIndex = arc4random() % numberOfImages;
    //    MainImage *imageView = [self.mainImages objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    //    self.mainImageView.image = imageView.mainTextImage;
    NSLog(@"Selected Random Image %i", randomIndex);
}
```

This is the debug output:

```
2014-10-24 21:04:48.276 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 33
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 73
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 65
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 62
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 53
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 15
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 82
2014-10-24 21:04:48.277 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 70
2014-10-24 21:04:48.278 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 26
2014-10-24 21:04:48.278 StackPlayground[25831:6132347] Selected Random Image 50
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I did have the (int) removed at first, but I would get an error saying "implicit conversion loses integer precision:'NSUInteger'(aka 'Unsigned Long') to 'int'."
Turning it into an integer solved that problem.

Comment: What type of object is self.mainImages?

Comment: self.mainImages is an NSArray

Comment: Wow thank you so much for taking the time to do that for me. Are you also saying that I should have an NSMutableArray instead of just an NSArray? I will look closer at all that in a little bit (a bit busy right now)

Comment: Sorry it's Friday night here and I have beer now. No an NSArray is fine. I used a mutable array to fill up an array quickly with 100 image views to simulate something you may have. I then copy that mutable array to a NSArray making it mirror what you have exactly with self.mainImages exactly. Gut feeling is your NSArray self.mainImages is either not initialised correctly or the images are not finding there way in there. Post the lines of code where you do init and fill your Array and we'll see if the problem is there.

Comment: Haha sounds like a good night! Here is the code of the objects being added into the Array.
`-(NSArray *)mainImages
{
    MainImage *redText = [[MainImage alloc] init];
    redText.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redText.png"];

    MainImage *orangeText = [[MainImage alloc] init];
    orangeText.mainTextImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeText.png"];
    
    NSArray *mainImages = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    return mainImages;
}`

Im sorry im new to this site as well and cant get the code to line up properly. I also had to remove many objects to make it fit but theyre al the same method

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what you need.

```
- (NSArray *)mainImages {
    NSArray *mainImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"purpleText.png"]
                           ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteText.png"]
                           ,[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackText.png"]
                           ,nil];
    return mainImages;
}
```

Have a good night

Comment: So that line of code actually was not needed :) I changed the array back, and changed the init line to `NSArray *mainImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: blackText, whiteText, redText, nil];`

Then in my viewDidLoad, before caling the method of updateGamePlay I had to add this, because the array is located in a class file called Factory
`Factory *factory = [[Factory alloc] init];
    self.mainImages = [factory mainImages];`